# Problema com *ngIf: Cannot read property 'indexvariacaoatributo' of undefined

Tags: angular

Tenho um formulário reativo e eu preciso mostrar esse card somente quando no meu array `listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo` for diferente de `null`. Acontece que inicialmente não existe o `indexvariacaoatributo`, então ele retorna:

> Cannot read property 'indexvariacaoatributo' of undefined

O que eu tentei:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of variacoes.controls; let i = index;">
<div *ngIf="listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo !== undefined && listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo !== null" class="animacaogeral animated zoomIn">
```

Existe alguma alternativa pra eu só mostrar esse card quando minha propriedade do meu array (indexvariacaoatributo) seja diferente de null antes dela existir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema não esteja no `indexvariacaoatributo`, provavelmente está no `listAtributos[i]`, que por algum motivo está `undefined` em algum elemento.

Tente isso, talvez resolva:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of variacoes.controls; let i = index;">
<div *ngIf="listAtributos[i] && listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo" class="animacaogeral animated zoomIn">
```

Resumindo, primeiro verifico se `listAtributos[i]` existe e depois verifico se `listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo` existe, se o item for `null`, `''`, `0` ou `undefined` ele irá retornar `false` em um `if`, `operador ternário` e etc.